# Problems with getting application packages via PackageManager in a recyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-package-managers

I'm trying to create an andorid launcher with an app drawer implemented via a recyclerview - basically I just want to have a list of all installed apps on the device.

Currently when I run the activity it crashes and I am not too sure why. I think the problem is that I'm not pulling the application packages correctly from the phone and the onBindViewHolder therefore crashes because I'm giving it null object references, but I'm not sure where exactly the problem with the package manager is.

This is the activity that holds the recyclerview, ***AppDrawer.java***:

```
public class AppDrawer extends AppCompatActivity {


    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.app_drawer);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.appsList);

        // add this
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        AppAdapter adapter = new AppAdapter(this);

        // replace this line by this two. (you should not call adapter method directly).
        // adapter.onCreateViewHolder(recyclerView, 0);    
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        // notify the adapter that the data has changed
        //recyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This is the ***AppAdapter.java***:

```
public class AppAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AppAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<AppObject> appsList;

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView textView;
        public ImageView img;

        //This is the subclass ViewHolder which simply
        //'holds the views' for us to show on each row
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            //Finds the views from our row.xml
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            int pos = getAdapterPosition();
            Context context = v.getContext();

            Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(appsList.get(pos).getName());
            context.startActivity(launchIntent);
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), appsList.get(pos).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }



    public AppAdapter(Context c) {

        //This is where we build our list of app details, using the app
        //object we created to store the label, package name and icon

        PackageManager pm = c.getPackageManager();
        appsList = new ArrayList<AppObject>();

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        List<ResolveInfo> allApps = pm.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
        for(ResolveInfo ri:allApps) {
            AppObject app = new AppObject(ri.loadLabel(pm).toString(), ri.activityInfo.packageName, ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(pm), false);
//            app.getName() = ri.loadLabel(pm);
//            app.getPackageName() = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
//            app.getImage() = ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(pm);
            appsList.add(app);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AppAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        //Here we use the information in the list we created to define the views

        String appLabel = appsList.get(i).getName();
        String appPackage = appsList.get(i).getPackageName();
        Drawable appIcon = appsList.get(i).getImage();

        TextView textView = viewHolder.textView;
        textView.setText(appLabel);
        ImageView imageView = viewHolder.img;
        imageView.setImageDrawable(appIcon);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        //This method needs to be overridden so that Androids knows how many items
        //will be making it into the list

        return appsList.size();
    }


    @Override
    public AppAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        //This is what adds the code we've written in here to our target view
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_drawer_item, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }
}
```

The ***AppObject.java***:

```
public class AppObject {
    private String  name,
                    packageName;
    private Drawable image;
    private Boolean isAppInDrawer;

    public AppObject(String packageName, String name, Drawable image, Boolean isAppInDrawer) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.packageName = packageName;
        this.isAppInDrawer = isAppInDrawer;
    }

    public String getPackageName() {
        return packageName;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public Drawable getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public Boolean getIsAppInDrawer() {return isAppInDrawer;}

    public void setPackageName(String packageName) {
        this.packageName = packageName;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setImage(Drawable image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    public void setIsAppInDrawer(Boolean appInDrawer) {
        this.isAppInDrawer = appInDrawer;
    }
}
```

And this is the error message i am getting when I try to run the code:

```
I/Surface: opservice is null false
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@365f0dd
E/OpApplicationPackageManagerInjector: Application package com.oneplus.iconpack.square not found
E/OpApplicationPackageManagerInjector: Application package com.oneplus.iconpack.square not found
I/chatty: uid=10302(com.example.launcherapplication) identical 36 lines
E/OpApplicationPackageManagerInjector: Application package com.oneplus.iconpack.square not found
W/cherapplicatio: resources.arsc in APK '/data/app/com.oneplus.gallery-u0eFcDkuFtHGko86_UqHPA==/base.apk' is compressed.
E/OpApplicationPackageManagerInjector: Application package com.oneplus.iconpack.square not found
I/chatty: uid=10302(com.example.launcherapplication) identical 24 lines
E/OpApplicationPackageManagerInjector: Application package com.oneplus.iconpack.square not found
W/cherapplicatio: resources.arsc in APK '/data/app/com.facebook.orca-omRvfq_ufIlgi54ffkzO9g==/base.apk' is compressed.
E/OpApplicationPackageManagerInjector: Application package com.oneplus.iconpack.square not found
I/chatty: uid=10302(com.example.launcherapplication) identical 58 lines
E/OpApplicationPackageManagerInjector: Application package com.oneplus.iconpack.square not found
V/ViewRootImpl: The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed
I/Surface: opservice is null false
D/DecorView: onWindowFocusChangedFromViewRoot hasFocus: true, DecorView@ef5993e[AppDrawer]
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.launcherapplication, PID: 15904
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.launcherapplication.AppAdapter.onBindViewHolder(AppAdapter.java:82)
        at com.example.launcherapplication.AppAdapter.onBindViewHolder(AppAdapter.java:18)
//FILLER ERROR MESSAGES//
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15904 SIG: 9
```

Comment: The line ` textView.setText(appLabel)` is the source of the error according to the logcat you posted. Make sure that the line `textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text)` in the view holder actually finds the _TextView_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Create new TextView within OnBindViewHolder,call viewHolder's textview directly and make sure your findViewById() calls correct id.(based on your logCat error)

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AppAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

       viewHolder.textView.setText(appLabel);
       viewHolder.img.setImageDrawable(appIcon);}
```